# asp.net repeater control

Tags: asp.net, repeater

what i am trying to do is display an image in a repeater. I am getting the image name from the database but i am trying to reference the image name from a image folder, at the moment this is what i have:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="Server" ImageUrl='~/Images/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductImage")%>' />
```

but it is not working, only the image name is displayed in the repeater.

Please any help will do guys.
Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: What is contained in `ProductImage`? The binary representation of the image? A URL fragment? What is the container it belongs to? How is it bound to the repeater?

Comment: What i did is created a upload button, and the upload button stores the name of the image in the database and the images extension eg. "Flowers.jpg", and the actual image file gets store in the folder "Images". So i am trying to display the image in the repeater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="Server" 
       ImageUrl='<%# "~/Images/" + Eval("ProductImage") %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML img tag instead:

```
<img src='~/Images/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductImage")%>'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="Server" ImageUrl="<%# "~/Images/" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductImage").ToString() %>" />
```